# How does Blinded and Confused work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I have a doubt about the interaction between Binding Flash and Blinded and Confused.

- Normal enemies in this case are blinded for 3 seconds, but if the 25% chance of Blinded and Confused triggers what happens? They are not blind anymore and attacks near enemies instead?
- What happens to elite enemies, can they be also affected by confusion? If yes, and they attack each other, they always hit or they have 30% miss chance?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auDv6cf2PBM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can shine some light on this as a regular user of this rune.

- If you trigger the 25% chance to confuse the enemy, they are **NOT**
  blinded, they instead get the "charmed" status and begin attacking
  other mobs.
- Elite mobs **CAN** be affected by the confusion. I can't say for certain
  whether their hit chance is modified, but I assume it is rolled the
  same way it would be against a player but instead taking the other
  mob's internal stats into consideration.

Hope this helps.